# Trying to make theme dropdown menu OnClick instead of hover

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, navigation

[Sorry if this is a dup to anyone, I was asked by the admins to move it to overflow]

I'm using the DIVI theme and making some relatively simple modifications to it to better suit my needs. One thing I'm having some difficulty with though surprisingly is swapping out its vertical menu's hover state drop downs to onclick functionality.

I've put together an example of the code below here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jdcutter/4aLu7nvp/5/)

```
$('ul.top-menu').children('.menu-item-has-children').click(function(){
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');
}).children('ul').find('.menu-item').click(function (event) { //select all the `.child` elements and stop the propagation of click events on the elements
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Oddly, though I can't seem to remove the hover state functionality from the menu. An example of DIVI can be found here: [DIVI](http://www.elegantthemes.com/demo/?theme=Divi)

Note: You'll need to go to headers in the navigation and choose the dark vertical navigation to replicate my layout.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Comment: What do you need only remove hover state ?

Comment: I need to replace the menu's hover state with a click state. I've gone through the style sheets and removed the hover state in previous efforts to resolve the change, however, no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme developer produced a result that produced the required result. The alteration to swap the functionality of the page navigation of DIVI is done in a file titled frontend-builder-scripts.js found in the DIVI folder directory /includes/builder/scripts/frontend-builder-scripts.js

To alter the hover to click swap the following code found on line 1074(Top line below) from .hover to .click.

```
$et_top_menu.find( 'li' ).hover( function() {
     if ( ! $(this).closest( 'li.mega-menu' ).length || $(this).hasClass( 'mega-menu' ) ) {
     $(this).addClass( 'et-show-dropdown' );
     $(this).removeClass( 'et-hover' ).addClass( 'et-hover' );
            et_menu_hover_triggered = true;
}
```

to

```
$et_top_menu.find( 'li' ).click( function() {
     if ( ! $(this).closest( 'li.mega-menu' ).length || $(this).hasClass( 'mega-menu' ) ) {
     $(this).addClass( 'et-show-dropdown' );
     $(this).removeClass( 'et-hover' ).addClass( 'et-hover' );
            et_menu_hover_triggered = true;
}
```

Comment: Not good practice to alter theme files -- any updates will write over the alterations. Best to extend the function in a safe area. The theme options provides this and would be best to add custom scripts before the closing body tag. Unbind the hover and attach the click event is the proper solution.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you should use classes that theme uses to manage showing and hiding menu in order to keep it compatible.

**CODE RESPOSIBLE FOR HOVER MENU (custom.js):**

```
var $et_top_menu = $( 'ul.nav' );

$et_top_menu.find( 'li' ).hover( function() {
    if ( ! $(this).closest( 'li.mega-menu' ).length || $(this).hasClass( 'mega-menu' ) ) {
        $(this).addClass( 'et-show-dropdown' );
        $(this).removeClass( 'et-hover' ).addClass( 'et-hover' );
    }
}, function() {
    var $this_el = $(this);

    $this_el.removeClass( 'et-show-dropdown' );

    setTimeout( function() {
        if ( ! $this_el.hasClass( 'et-show-dropdown' ) ) {
            $this_el.removeClass( 'et-hover' );
        }
    }, 200 );
} );
```

**HOW TO UNBIND TRIGGERING HOVER EVENT #1 (if you want to do this somewhere else after it is initialized in custom.js):**

```
 $( 'ul.nav li' ).off("hover");
```

**HOW TO UNBIND TRIGGERING HOVER EVENT #2 (if you want to modify custom.js right after the code):**

```
$et_top_menu.find( 'li' ).off("hover");
```

**HOW TO UNBIND TRIGGERING HOVER EVENT #3 (if you want to modify custom.js :**

Just remove the code and replace it with your on click event code

**HOW TO MAKE ON CLICK EVENT - if you want to leave previous hover code - past below the hover code or use it in your place - note it must be used after custom.js or inside after hover code:**

```
$( 'ul.nav li' ).off("hover");

$et_top_menu.find( 'li' ).click( function() {
    if ( ! $(this).closest( 'li.mega-menu' ).length || $(this).hasClass( 'mega-menu' ) ) {
        $(this).toggleClass( 'et-show-dropdown' );
        $(this).toggleClass( 'et-hover' );
    }
});
```

The code i gave you has no anitmation so do it on your own. Simplest way is to use CSS for example:

```
<YOUR SELECTOR> {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

FIDDLE EXAMPLE - it turns off HOVER event and set up ON CLICK event.

http://jsfiddle.net/gwn9aqxs/2/

I added some CSS classes in order to keep it compatible with your theme css classes. I added "nav" classs to parent UL just like it in your theme and i added "mega-menu" class to li parent of ul.sub-menu just like in your theme.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-through. Really a great answer, sadly it doesn't resolve as expected in DIVI. I had previously tried to make a very similar adjustment through the suggestion of the theme developer, however, for some reason the hover state persists and ignores the request to switch to a click state.

Comment: Try to call $( 'ul.nav li' ).off("hover"); and set up simple on click event with alert(1); Try it. It is impossible to not work :) Could you give me address of the website?

Comment: The most important thing is to place it after it initialize (which is in custom.js). Remember that the code in custom.js is inside

$(document).ready( function(){

Comment: I can't share the address of the site, but here is a link displaying your code in the custom.js. http://emailimagestorage.com/capture-1.png Everything look as it should to you?